# How to enable Excel macros for only one sheet

Tags: excel, vba

In my excel sheet I am validating that a specific column should not be empty and its values should be unique. This validation should only be performed on Sheet1 but it is working for other sheets also.
My code is

```
 Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, _ Cancel As Boolean)



    Dim rngCell As Range 
   Dim  lngLstRow As Long
    lngLstRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    For Each rngCell In Range("A1:A" & lngLstRow)
     If rngCell.Value = 0 Then MsgBox ("Please enter a name in cell " & rngCell.Address) rngCell.Select 
     End If
     Next
     End Sub
```

The second validation for unique values is done by data validation functionality in excel.

Answer (score -1):

1. How about a ActiveWorksheet.name check ?
   like

   ```
    Dim Sh as Object, rngCell as Range, lngLstRow As Long
    For Each Sh in WorkSheets
    If Sh.Name = "SpecialName" Then 'YourCodeNext
    lngLstRow = Sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    For Each rngCell In Range("A1:A" & lngLstRow).Cells
    If rngCell.Value = 0 Then MsgBox _
    ("Please enter a name in cell " & rngCell.Address) rngCell.Select 
    End If
    Next rngCell 
    End If
    Next Sh
   ```

Or if you know specific value of cell or range in your list.

```
For Each Sh in WorkSheets
If Sh.Range("K10").Value = "YourUnicValue" Then 'YourCodeNext
```

Also I'm not sure about your rngCell, if you want to check every cell in range, you need to use it like that.

```
      For Each rngCell In Range("A1:A" & lngLstRow).Cells
```

Comment: This code isn't working. My first sheet named is validate and second one is named as start. After applying the for each loop to check the name it is still validating both the sheets. I just want validation to work on the validate sheet.